# Type check based on the argument value

Tags: typescript

Are there any ways to check types based on the argument value

For example,
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKAhgJwOYCMAXDAORQCmAHlKTAD5lgIC2FOAlsKQDQy54ATCWicweBjGYsARuwCUJAG4gOAExgBvAFAw9MAPQGYAGxB4u2gL7btiZBnLVafAEQQ1cV-MPGoATwAHChgOCBhQHBwKYCg7JGBHShpeGAIfIxgA4NDwjmQQKJi4+0TSaXYuVPTfLKCQsIjC6Nj4h3LWSu43Dy8Mv3rcpqLYoA)

```
const func = (arg1: 'text' | 'numeric', arg2: string | number): void {
    // logic
}

func('text', "sdf") // type is correct
func('text', 1) // type is incorrect
func('numeric', 1) // type is correct
func('numeric', "sdf") // type is correct
```

When `arg1` takes 'text' value, `arg2` type should be string type, and when `arg1` takes `numeric` value, `arg2` should be `number` type.

I tried conditional type but it didnt work well.

Comment: What do you mean _"didnt work well"_ - give a [mre]. Have you considered [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
function func(arg1: 'text', arg2: string): void;
function func(arg1: 'numeric', arg2: number): void;
function func(arg1: 'text' | 'numeric', arg2: string | number): void {
    // logic
}

func('text', "sdf") // type is correct
func('text', 1) // type is incorrect
func('numeric', 1) // type is correct
func('numeric', "sdf") // type is correct
```

Check it on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAnNAFAQwE4HMCMAXMgOQwCmAHjCQDTI64BMxAzjNnBLgJTEBuCOABMA3KEixEKNFCx4ipCGAC25TlDoM8LZMpUAjdX2SCR42fCSpJ8gsTJUayAD5LV6uJvqNd7TtyueqpG2CZmwsgA3sDIccgA9AnIADYIuF7AAL7AEhiO1FoARKzCIEU8ickwAJ4ADuTIcKzIUAjY2OSweXIFNPT4lUnItQ1NLVxtHV0wPegk+p7eyINVI-WNza3tnd2y84saxaXlQ9Ub49vT3UA).

Be aware that while TypeScript prevents calling the function with "wrong" values, its power is limited to the information that it has at compile time. If the first argument passed on a call of `func()` is a variable, it cannot help any more.
Make sure that you check the values of both arguments in the function body and handle the undesired situations properly.